# Python : Set method attribute from within method

Tags: python, python-decorators

I am trying to make a python decorator that adds attributes to methods of a class so that I can access and modify those attributes from within the method itself.  The decorator code is

```
from types import MethodType
class attribute(object):

    def __init__(self, **attributes):
        self.attributes = attributes

    def __call__(self, function):

        class override(object):

            def __init__(self, function, attributes):
                self.__function = function
                for att in attributes:
                    setattr(self, att, attributes[att])

            def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
                return self.__function(*args, **kwargs)

            def __get__(self, instance, owner):
                return MethodType(self, instance, owner) 

        retval = override(function, self.attributes)
        return retval
```

I tried this decorator on the toy example that follows.

```
    class bar(object):

        @attribute(a=2)
        def foo(self):
            print self.foo.a
            self.foo.a = 1
```

Though I am able to access the value of attribute 'a' from within foo(), I can't set it to another value.  **Indeed, when I call `bar().foo()`, I get the following AttributeError.**

```
AttributeError: 'instancemethod' object has no attribute 'a'
```

Why is this?  More importantly how can I achieve my goal?

---

**Edit**

Just to be more specific, I am trying to find a simple way to implement static variable that are located within class methods.  Continuing from the example above, I would like instantiate `b = bar()`, call both `foo()` and `doo()` methods and then access `b.foo.a` and `b.doo.a` later on.

```
    class bar(object):

        @attribute(a=2)
        def foo(self):
            self.foo.a = 1

        @attribute(a=4)
        def doo(self):
            self.foo.a = 3
```

Comment: I was wondering what was use case of such construct? Since You want to set this attribute, why not in making it a foo's argument?

Comment: @brainovergrow, the objective is to do something equivalent to static variables in C++.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best way to do this is to *not do it at all*.

First of all, there is no need for an attribute decorator; you can just assign it yourself:

```
class bar(object):
    def foo(self):
        print self.foo.a
        self.foo.a = 1
    foo.a = 2
```

However, this still encounters the same errors. You need to do:

```
self.foo.__dict__['a'] = 1
```

You can instead use a metaclass...but that gets messy quickly.

On the other hand, there are cleaner alternatives.

You can use defaults:

```
def foo(self, a):
    print a[0]
    a[0] = 2
foo.func_defaults = foo.func_defaults[:-1] + ([2],)
```

Of course, my preferred way is to avoid this altogether and use a callable class ("functor" in C++ words):

```
class bar(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = self.foo_method(self)
    class foo_method(object):
        def __init__(self, bar):
            self.bar = bar
            self.a = 2
        def __call__(self):
            print self.a
            self.a = 1
```

Or just use classic class attributes:

```
class bar(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
    def foo(self):
        print self.a
        self.a = 2
```

If it's that you want to hide `a` from derived classes, use whatever private attributes are called in Python terminology:

```
class bar(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__a = 1 # this will be implicitly mangled as __bar__a or similar
    def foo(self):
        print self.__a
        self.__a = 2
```

**EDIT:** You want static attributes?

```
class bar(object):
    a = 1
    def foo(self):
        print self.a
        self.a = 2
```

**EDIT 2:** If you want static attributes visible to only the current function, you can use [PyExt](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyext)'s *modify_function*:

```
import pyext

def wrap_mod(*args, **kw):
    def inner(f):
        return pyext.modify_function(f, *args, **kw)
    return inner

class bar(object):
    @wrap_mod(globals={'a': [1]})
    def foo(self):
        print a[0]
        a[0] = 2
```

It's slightly ugly and hackish. But it works.

My recommendation would be just to use double underscores:

```
class bar(object):
    __a = 1
    def foo(self):
        print self.__a
        self.__a = 2
```

Although this *is* visible to the other functions, it's invisible to anything else (actually, it's there, but it's mangled).

**FINAL EDIT:** Use this:

```
import pyext

def wrap_mod(*args, **kw):
    def inner(f):
        return pyext.modify_function(f, *args, **kw)
    return inner

class bar(object):
    @wrap_mod(globals={'a': [1]})
    def foo(self):
        print a[0]
        a[0] = 2
    foo.a = foo.func_globals['a']

b = bar()
b.foo() # prints 1
b.foo() # prints 2
# external access
b.foo.a[0] = 77
b.foo() # prints 77
```

Comment: @kirbyfan64os, thanks for your answer.  The idea is to have the equivalent of static variables in C++.  Though assigning foo.a =2 is elegant, the only way to change attribute a from within the method seems to modify the function dictionary (self.foo.__dict__['a'] = 1) which isn't elegant.  The callable class idea is quite nice though.  Still I wonder why the python language does not implement more concise way to do this.

Comment: @kirbyfan64os, thanks for this.  However, I would like the static attribute to be at the method level.

Comment: @Francis What exactly do you mean? Is it so no outsiders can access the attribute, or so only that function can access the attribute?

Comment: @Francis I have a solution for the latter.

Comment: @kirbyfan64os, thanks again and sorry for having difficulty to be very specific.  That said, I want two different methods of the same class to use the same attribute name without sharing it's value like a static class level attribute would do.  In other words, if foo1() and foo2() are two methods of the same class both have a 'a' attribute , I would like to modify the value foo1.a without modifying foo2.a.  After a a given number of executions of both functions, I would then like to access the value of the 'a' attribute from outside the class scope.

Comment: @Francis That's what the `pyext` example I gave you does. To access externally, you need to use `the_function.func_globals['a']`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75334/discussion-between-francis-and-kirbyfan64sos).

Comment: @kirbyfan64os, thanks for the last edit.  Quite hackish but it works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

While You can accomplish Your goal by replacing `self.foo.a = 1` with `self.foo.__dict__['a'] = 1` it is generally not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Python2 - (and not Python3) - whenever you retrieve a method from an instance, a new `instance method` object is created  which is a wrapper to the original function defined in the class body.

The instance method is a rather transparent proxy to the function - you can  retrieve the function's attributes through it, but not set them - that is why setting an item in `self.foo.__dict__` works.

Alternatively you can reach the function object itself using: `self.foo.im_func` - the `im_func` attribute of instance methods point the underlying function.

Answer (score 0):

Based on other contributors's answers, I came up with the following workaround.  First, wrap a dictionnary in a class resolving non-existant attributes to the wrapped dictionnary such as the following code.

```
class DictWrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, d):
        self.d = d
    def __getattr__(self, key):
        return self.d[key]
```

Credits to [Lucas Jones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517241/is-there-any-trick-to-overload-the-dot-operator) for this code.

Then implement a `addstatic` decorator with a `statics` attribute that will store the *static* attributes.

```
class addstatic(object):

    def __init__(self, **statics):
        self.statics = statics

    def __call__(self, function):

        class override(object):

            def __init__(self, function, statics):
                self.__function = function
                self.statics = DictWrapper(statics)

            def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
                return self.__function(*args, **kwargs)

            def __get__(self, instance, objtype):
                from types import MethodType
                return MethodType(self, instance)

        retval = override(function, self.statics)
        return retval
```

The following code is an example of how the `addstatic` decorator can be used on methods.

```
   class bar(object):

        @attribute(a=2, b=3)
        def foo(self):
            self.foo.statics.a = 1
            self.foo.statics.b = 2
```

Then, playing with an instance of the `bar` class yields :

```
>>> b = bar()
>>> b.foo.statics.a
2
>>> b.foo.statics.b
3
>>> b.foo()
>>> b.foo.statics.a
3
>>> b.foo.statics.b
5
```

The reason for using this statics dictionnary follows jsbueno's answer which suggest that what I want would require overloading the dot operator of and instance method wrapping the foo function, which I am not sure is possible.  Of course, the method's attribute could be set in `self.foo.__dict__`, but since it not recommended (as suggested by brainovergrow), I came up with this workaround.  I am not certain this would be recommended either and I guess it is up for comments.