# Is there a .= operator in python? If not, how do I make it?

Tags: python, operator-overloading

```
 i += 1
```

can be used to shorten

```
 i = i + 1
```

Now, I really want some

```
.=
```

operator to shorten painfull stuff like

```
some_long_df_name['some_equally_long_column_name'] = some_long_df_name['some_equally_long_column_name'].do_method()
```

into

```
some_long_df_name['some_equally_long_column_name'] .= do_method()
```

---

1. I know that i+=1 is not exactly the same as i = i+1  (inplace vs reassigning, see also the answer on this SO post [What is the difference between i = i + 1 and i += 1 in a 'for' loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41446833/what-is-the-difference-between-i-i-1-and-i-1-in-a-for-loop))
2. I looked at the

```
.__iXXX__
```

methods from python https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types and couldnt find what I was looking for.

So mostly I am looking for a good explanation why this operator/method isnt there, or some python hack/trick to overload/construct this operator myself.

Thanks !!

Comment: Have you already looked at [Is there any trick to “overload the dot operator”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5517241)

Comment: You can override existing operators but no, you can't add new operators to Python.

Comment: @JeanneDark No, I wasnt aware of this post. Will look into it, thanks

Comment: You might also want to look at `dict.get(key, [value])`

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard of such an operator but you could just do something like this to get rid of long names:

```
col = 'some_equally_long_column_name'

some_long_df_name[col] = some_long_df_name[col].do_method()
```

Also many pandas in-built functions have `inplace` parameter that will modify df in-place if set to True.